# Why are len() and is_empty() not defined in a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

Most patterns in Rust are captured by traits (`Iterator`, `From`, `Borrow`, etc.).

How come a pattern as pervasive as `len`/`is_empty` has no associated trait in the standard library? Would that cause problems which I do not foresee? Was it deemed useless? Or is it only that nobody thought of it (which seems unlikely)?

Answer (score 8):

> Was it deemed useless?

I would guess that's the reason.

What could you do with the knowledge that something is empty or has length 15? Pretty much nothing, unless you also have a way to access the elements of the collection for example. The trait that unifies collections is [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html). In particular an iterator can tell you how many elements its underlying collection has, but it also does a lot more.

Also note that should you need an `Empty` trait, you can create one and implement it for all standard collections, unlike interfaces in most languages. This is the power of traits. This also means that the standard library doesn't need to provide small utility traits for every single use case, they can be provided by libraries!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A use I would have for a Len trait would be for a Wrapper type to implement in when the wrapped type implements it, as in https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=640848942758654d880aa2cd2b10d28b . Of course, I can create the trait and implement it post-hoc on existing types (as I did in that example), but this can be tedious.

Comment: Also, if I may, the `Iterator` trait does *not* unify collections: an iterator and the collection it iterates over are two distinct things. And an iterator can not easily give you the exact size of the underlying collection. You must use either `size_hint`, which may only give you bounds, or `count`, which forces you to iterate over the whole collection. This is ok, because not all iterator can know in advance how many items they will yield. But this is why we could do with a separate `Len` trait ;-P

Comment: Are you aware of [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html)? Not that `ExactSizeIterator: Iterator` because again, there isn't much you can do with just the bounds.

Comment: Your wrapper is not a very good example. Sure if a thing wraps something that implements the `Whatever` trait, it can probably implement `Whatever` as well, but that doesn't show what you can *do* with `Whatever`.

Comment: I'm not arguing that the `Len` trait *alone* is very useful, but in conjunction with `IntoIterator` it could be... As for `ExactSizeIterator`, thanks for the link, I didn't know it and it can indeed be useful. But again my interest here is about the "collection", not the iterators it produces...

Comment: I agree `Len` would make sense as a trait. It could also be combined with `Index` and `IndexMut` to give bounds for sequence access.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a late but perhaps useful answer here. Depending on what exactly you need, using the `slice` type might be a good option, rather than specifying a trait. Slices have `len()`, `is_empty()`, and other useful methods ([full docs here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html)). Consider the following:

```rs
use core::fmt::Display;

fn printme<T: Display>(x: &[T]) {
    println!("length: {}, empty: ", x.len());

    for c in x {
        print!("{}, ", c);
    }

    println!("\nDone!");
}

fn main() {
    let s = "This is some string";

    // Vector
    let vv: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();
    printme(&vv);

    // Array
    let x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    printme(&x);

    // Empty
    let y:Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    printme(&y);
}
```

`printme` can accept either a vector or an array. Most other things that it accepts will need some massaging.

I think maybe the reason for there being no `Length` trait is that most functions will either a) work through an iterator without needing to know its length (with `Iterator`), or b) require `len` because they do some sort of random element access, in which case a slice would be the best bet. In the first case, knowing length may be helpful to pre-allocate memory of some size, but `size_hint` takes care of this when used for anything like `Vec::with_capacity`, or `ExactSizeIterator` for anything that needs specific allocations. Most other cases would probably need to be collected to a vector at some point within the function, which has its `len`.

Playground link to my example here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a034c2e8b75775449afa110c05858e7

Comment: Not everything is a slice (maps, sets, linked lists, `VecDeque`...)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman of course, it is not a situation that works in every case. That is what I meant by `Most other things that it accepts will need some massaging`